# Adding sum of rows in a dynamic column using ClosedXML

Tags: c#, blazor-webassembly, closedxml

Is there any way at all to add up (sum up) the contents of the cells (Rows) of a given column whose number of possible rows (cells) are dynamic, that is, the number of rows are not fixed, in an excel worksheet? I've been trying without any meaningful result, I want to calculate the Total of the the Last column named "Total Inc Vat" which is so dynamic; Here is a snippet of my codes.

```
            var workbook = new XLWorkbook();
            var worksheet =  workbook.Worksheets.Add("data");

            string filename = "Data from" + " "+ reportParams.StartDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy") + " to "+ reportParams.EndDate.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");

            worksheet.Cell(1, 1).Value = filename;
            // column header 
            worksheet.Range(1, 1, 1, 8).Merge().AddToNamed("data");
            // column names  range to be formatted 
            worksheet.Range(3, 1, 3, 8).AddToNamed("data");
            // format Total Inc Vat column to currency
            worksheet.Column(8).Style.NumberFormat.Format= "0.00";
            
            // column names 
            worksheet.Cell(3, 1).Value = "Document Date";
            worksheet.Cell(3, 2).Value = "Document Number";
            worksheet.Cell(3, 3).Value = "Description";
            worksheet.Cell(3, 4).Value = "Project Code";
            worksheet.Cell(3, 5).Value = "Project Name";
            worksheet.Cell(3, 6).Value = "Client Name";
            worksheet.Cell(3, 7).Value = "Client Account";
            worksheet.Cell(3, 8).Value = "Total Inc Vat";
            
            //
            var titlesStyle = workbook.Style;
            titlesStyle.Font.Bold = true;
            titlesStyle.Alignment.Horizontal = XLAlignmentHorizontalValues.Center;
            titlesStyle.Fill.BackgroundColor = XLColor.Cyan;
            
            // format all titles in one shot
            workbook.NamedRanges.NamedRange("data").Ranges.Style = titlesStyle;

           
            worksheet.Cell(4, 1).SetValue(results);
            worksheet.Columns().AdjustToContents();
```

Answer (score 0):

This is all needed to add. Where 4 in `Cell()` is the cell row a `results.Count()` is everything generated in that cell.

```
// calculate average of Total Inc Vat
worksheet.Cell(4 + results.Count(), 8).FormulaA1 = @$"=SUM(H4:H{3 + results.Count()})";
```